# Localization file is not used

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a problem, I changed stuff in my Main Storyboard, saved it, and then xCode crashed and the Main Storyboard wasn't found by xCode after i restarted. I solved that by deleting the references of my storyboard and added the file back.

**Now the problem:**
My Localization files aren't used by my app, the localization files of my Storyboard and my Strings.

[image]

I have tried several things, but still doesn't seem to work. Need some guidance on how to make this work again.

Thanks. Regards.

Comment: 1. check target membership (View - Utilities - Show Utilities)

2. look inside translated files - check that you not mistakenly overwritten them with base translation

3. clean the project (Product Clean), reset and restart simulator, or delete the app from device - just a precaution

Comment: Performing all those steps, and deleting the references and stuff did it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these steps:

1. check target membership (View - Utilities - Show Utilities)
2. look inside translated files
3. clean the project
4. Delete app from simulator or device

Normally all of that should work. If not try disable the location file, but don't remove it. Then add it again.